# polyfit function conversion from matlab to r

Tags: r, matlab, polynomial-math

So matlab help has the following description :

```
[P, S, MU] = POLYFIT[X,Y,N]
```

I know what the input variables mean, but i cant calculate the `MU` "manually". The `MU` i need for calculating the area of a peak.

I need to convert source code from MATLAB to R, but don't know what's the best to do.

Comment: Where can we find the function? What did you try? Please provide additional information.

Comment: Its in MATLAB, and i tried to use the function poly() from R to get the same results. It works, same results. But, while boot of them supplies the coefficients, i don't know how to calculate the MU variable provided by the POLYFIT function of Matlab.

Comment: Once you have the function fit, the integrate() function will allow you to calculate the area of a function between two x-limits.

Comment: Ok, i tried that to but if there are multiple peaks that over lap each other -> how you calculate it ? So i could break into Gaussian signals separate them but there is the problem of limits again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MU is given as [mu1,mu2] and is used for centering and scaling the data so that the problem will have good numerical properties. mu1 is the mean of x and mu2 is the standard deviation of x.

See info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).

Comment: Problem with following your link : for MATLAB std function there is the sd function of R, mean exits but the values don't correspond. Do you want example code ? But i accept you're response when we finish.

Comment: @ZsurzsaLaszlo-Andras so you calculated the mean of X and the std of X and these are not equal to mu1 and mu2?

Comment: Yeah so if i for example calculate it in matlab using the functions and using polyfit the results are not the same.

Comment: Well I just tried in matlab: x=rand(10,1);y=3*x+1;[p,s,mu]=polyfit(x,y,1) and the mu1,mu2 were equal to mean(x),std(x) so it works.